# Google App Engine + Objectify: Register object once?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, objectify

I recently got objectify working with app engine, but I'm having trouble with registering a class for objectify multiple times. While developing in Eclipse, which recompiles and runs again every time the localhost is refreshed, the script that registers the student is run multiple times, and crashes the program after just one refresh.

```
<%
//In my main.jsp file, which is the main interactive html page
ObjectifyService.register(Object.class);
%>
```

How can I ensure that this script is only run once? Is there a way to check if a class is registered with objectify? I followed a suggestion on another stackoverflow thread to do the following:

```
public class Object {
    ...
    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(Object.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

This gave me a different error. How can I solve this?

Comment: "Crashes"? "A different error"? Be specific! Include stacktraces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it on your [ServletContextListener](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#using_a_servletcontextlistener), specifically, on the contextInitialized() hook. This will ensure that the Objectify register code is only executed once when the server is warming up.

Answer (score 1):

by looking on a reliable example like this:

[Objectify in JSP](http://code.google.com/p/fulltext-search-in-objectify/source/browse/trunk/guestbook/war/guestbook.jsp?spec=svn7&r=7)

you can find similar attempt to register the class, BUT... Read the comments from the example:

> // BE CAREFUL with this line! This a example, but in a real world project, you should look a better
>   // place for register an entity, at the very beginning of your application is recommended.

So... You probably have a java class in which you implemented several methods like: get/put/delete etc... and in that java class you should place the code to register the class

```
    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(Object.class);
    }
```

OR, look for some other place that is being called once upon the application starts

Comment: The [Objectify documentation](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices#How_NOT_To_Register_Entities) is quite explicit about this.

Comment: i sayed to add the static block inside a class that is implements the CRUD operations... so if you put the static block inside it, (and you must create an instance of it before using the CRUD operations) it should be fine, i did not say to put the static block with registration inside the "Object" class itself

Comment: I am sorry for misleading a bit. I referred more to the general situation than to your correct advice. What you describe, putting the registering into a DAO, is one paragraph above the one I linked to: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices#Use_a_DAO